# Hide DIV, if LAST unchecked checkbox - jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

Currently, when a checkbox is checked, a div will show. Although, how can I do, so when I uncheck that div (IF IT IS THE LAST UNCHECKED DIV), the DIV will hide?

Currently, I only have the code to show the div:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $("#userInfo").show(this.checked);  

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
   if('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').length == $('input[type="checkbox"]').length)
     ///code for hiding the div
});
```

this can help,
I have searched for all un-checked if number of un-checked is equal to number of checkboxes then all checkboxes are checked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Wroking **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L2SQ7/)**

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    $("#userInfo")
    .toggle(($('input:checkbox:checked').length == $('input:checkbox').length));  
});
```

This code will show the `div` only if all the checkboxes are checked. I hope that is what you are looking for.